# JavaFx2 Controller method not found

Tags: java, javafx-2, builder, scene

Could someone tell me what on earth is going on???

```
@FXML
public void whatever(MouseEvent event){
    //do whatever
}


@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}
```

}

I want the method to be called when i click on a specific pane. So in the pane i have this code (in the Xml file)

```
onMouseClicked="#whatever" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0".....
```

and yet somehow i get:

"Handler event is not accesible, make public or annotate with @FXML"

Comment: I use scene builder by the way if that is of importance

Comment: Have you imported correct javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent?

Comment: can you provide all the FXML file ? to see if you correctly linked your fxml to your controller

Comment: javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent

i did not know this...
stupid Netbeans ;)